# Allow URL Parameters - Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, manifest.json

I am using content script and in my manifest, I added the url like this and it works fine:

```
"matches": {
   "http://example.com/profile/*",
   "http://example.com/profile/*"
}
```

However, what I am actually trying to achieve is allowing parameters in the url, so it only works on `"http://example.com/profile/hobbies?*"` but not on `"http://example.com/profile/music?*"`

Is there a way to add this kind of permission in the matches section?

Comment: Use [exclude_matches and exclude_globs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot for your helps man! You are the king!